# Change Woocommerce Product Categories Widget 'Title' based on Product Category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I'm looking for a way to change the widget title of Woocommerce Product Categories Widget based on the category I'm viewing.

> Category 1 -----> Display Title of Widget for Category 1
>
> ```
> - Sub Category
> - Sub Category
> - Sub Category
> ```
>
> Category 2  -----> Display Title of Widget for Category 1
>
> ```
> - Sub Category
> - Sub Category
> - Sub Category
> ```

I'm working with this but can't seem to target the widget title and create the if else statement correctly.

```
function retitle_woo_category_widget() {
    // If 'Category' 1 is being viewed...
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Category 1', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        //... Remove the images
        return __('Title of Widget for Category 1');
    }
    else {
    // If 'Category' 2 is being viewed...
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Category 2', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        return __('Title of Widget for Category 2');
}

add_filter ( 'widget_title' , 'retitle_woo_category_widget');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

widget_title has 3 arguments you can use to check for the appopriate category. Depending on that you can change the title by returning an alternative string. Keep in mind that this will affect any other widgets as well. Use this as a base:

```
function my_widget_title( $title, $instance, $id_base ) {
    if ( !is_single() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    $post_title = get_the_title();
    switch ( $id_base ) {
        case 'pages': return sprintf( '%s "%s"', $title, $post_title );
        case 'links': return sprintf( 'Links for "%s" post.', $post_title );
        // other widgets ...
        default: return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'my_widget_title', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for 2022!

```
//Customize Woocommerce Category Widget to show title of current category
function dynamic_product_category_widget($title, $widget_instance, $widget_id) {

    if ( $widget_id !== 'woocommerce_product_categories' )
        return $title;

    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $cat_title = '<p class="widget-title footer-widget">'.single_cat_title()."</p>";
        return $cat_title;
    } elseif ( is_product() ) {
        $cat = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );

        foreach ($cat as $categoria) {
            if($categoria->parent == 0){
                $topCategory = $categoria;
            }
        }
        return '<p class="widget-title footer-widget">'.$topCategory->name.'</p>';
    }
    
    return $title;
}
add_filter ( 'widget_title' , 'dynamic_product_category_widget', 10, 3);
```